# Unable to load CSV file into Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I've just started using Neo4j and have attempted to follow tutorials on YouTube about how to inport CSVs into Neo4j.

I am using the code below to try and import my CSV onto Neo4j by using Cypher:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/MATT/Documents/LL.csv" As csvline
MATCH(n) RETURN n
```

However, I keep receiving this error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your CSV file into the import directory of Neo4j installation. For OS X installations this directory is `<neo4j-home>/import`.

After, your `LOAD CSV` statement will looks like it:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///LL.csv" As csvline MATCH(n)
RETURN n
```

That is: the file URL is relative to the import directory.

Take a look in the [Neo4j File Locations docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations) and [Import CSV data guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/).

Comment: ***Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/Users/MATT/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/Users/MATT/Documents/LL.csv***                                                                                     I have been researching in what you have stated but cannot resolve the problem. It appears that it has located the resource but it cannot extract it. Your code was useful and it may be due to me creating an error.

Comment: Try adding the line `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true` in neo4j.conf file.

Comment: @Stabbathehut have you tried the above suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: once you put the file in your import folder, neo4j will use a path relative to that folder, so you also change your command to:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://LL.csv"

Comment: @BrunoPeres you also need to comment out #dbms.directories.import=import as mentioned by Robert Singh below.

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTIONS:

This is a security feature that is auto-enabled in neo4j 3.0 and above. It disallows files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem.

You have 2 Solutions/Options:

1. Leave the setting as is and simply place all CSV files to be read in the "import" directory(folder) located in the install directory(folder).
2. Change the security feature to allow the importation of CSVs from any directory in the filesystem.

### OPTION 1:

This option is straight forward, simply copy and paste all CSV files to be read in the "import" directory(folder) located in the install directory(folder).

Then use the path as follows for the file (eg. to load a CSV file "data.csv" which was pasted into the import directory(folder)

```
LOAD CSV file:///data.csv
```

### OPTION 2:

To allow any url or filepath to be imported, you must navigate to the neo4j.conf file. The file is found in the conf Folder in the install directory. Alternatively, you can simply search for the "neo4j.conf" file.

Upon locating the file open it (using Notepad or other). Then ensure that "dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true" below is NOT commented out (remove "#") && "dbms.directories.import=import" below is commented out (add "#").

```
# Determines if Cypher will allow using file URLs when loading data using
# `LOAD CSV`. Setting this value to `false` will cause Neo4j to fail `LOAD CSV`
# clauses that load data from the file system.
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the
# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.
#dbms.directories.import=import
```

Comment: NOTE: for EACH database/graph you create in Neo4j, you would have to navigate to the neo4j.conf file for that database/graph and repeat the process outline above.